# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class not found composer en php

Tags: php, composer

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy aprendiendo a hacer librerias en php con composer pero tengo un problema.

Esta es la estructura de mi libreria:

```
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── index.php
├── src
│   └── hola.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── composer
        ├── ClassLoader.php
        ├── InstalledVersions.php
        ├── LICENSE
        ├── autoload_classmap.php
        ├── autoload_namespaces.php
        ├── autoload_psr4.php
        ├── autoload_real.php
        ├── autoload_static.php
        ├── installed.json
        └── installed.php
```

Y este es el contenido de mi composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "nombre/paquete",
    "description": "",
    "type": "library",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Hola\\Saludo\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {}
}
```

Esto tengo dentro de `src/hola.php`:

```
namespace Hola\Saludo;

class Hola
{
    public static function hola()
    {
        echo "Hola :D";
    }
}
```

Y finalmente esto tengo dentro del `index.php`:

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once "./vendor/autoload.php";

use Hola\Saludo\Hola;

Hola::hola();

?>
```

Y de error tengo esto:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Hola\Saludo\Hola" not found in
> /var/www/index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> /var/www/index.php on line 9

Agradecería su ayuda ya que soy nuevo en esto y no se que tengo mal. Desde ya gracias :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando implementas composer y el autoload psr-4; tienes que seguir el estandar [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/), [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) y [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) de la [FIG](https://www.php-fig.org/).

Entonces apegandonos al estandar puedo ver que el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Hola\Saludo\Hola" not found in
> /var/www/index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> /var/www/index.php on line 9

Corresponde a una sintaxis erronea del estandar; el archivo que citas `hola.php` esta en minuscula, cuando los archivos que contengan clases debe **tener su primera letra en mayuscula**, tambien el nombre del archivo debe ser el mismo que el nombre de la clase dentro del namespaces.

por ejemplo si la clase de llama:

```php
class BugCatcher
{
}
```

el archivo debe llamarce:

```
BugCatcher.php
```

Recuerda que al hacer cualquier cambio debe ejecutar el comando:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era el problema :D